# Css3 quicklink container background

Tags: css

I have the following CSS3 code for a quick link container. I don't know why but the gradient background is not under the text.
If i remove the `float: left` from `div.quicklinks`, I will display the gradient background but i want some text to the left.
Thanks

```
div.quickLinksContainer {
    clear:both;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(179,175,176) 49%, rgb(237,237,237) 75%);
}
div.quickLinks {
    font-size: 12px;
    float:left;
}
.quickLinks h2 {
  color:#666666;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.quickLinks li a {
  color:#555555;
  text-decoration:initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the background isn't behind the content is because of

```
div.quickLinks {
    float:left;
}
```

If you rather put the background gradient directly inside `div.quickLinks` it will work.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MADXd/) for demo.

**EDIT**
On background on the comments:

When you float the content, the parent container, in this case `quickLinksContainer`, doesn't know how big the content is. Thus, for the container to have the correct size you'll have to specify it. For instance like this:

```
div.quickLinksContainer {
    height: 150px;
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MADXd/1/)

Comment: if i'll put the gradient inside only the text will have gradient....so....ugly....

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want a gradient background all over the quick link container (footer) not only behind the text....